# Sum over columns in dynamic range

Tags: python, pandas

I am working making a dynamic table by adding columns in same row, however, range of columns is determined based on two columns difference (high-low):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
  '10': [1, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
  '20': [20, 15, 12, 18, 32, 12],
  '30': [3, 11, 25, 32, 13, 4],
  '40': [32, 11, 9, 82, 2, 1],
  '50': [9, 5, 11, 11, 2, 5],
  'low': [12, 22, 18, 27, 23, 15],
  'high': [45, 41, 33, 54, 35, 45],
})

df

Index     10      20      30     40    50   low    high
0         1       20      3      32    9    12     45
1         10      15      11     11    5    22     41
2         20      12      25     9     11   18     33
3         30      18      32     82    11   27     54
4         40      32      13     2     2    23     35     
5         50      12      4      1     5    15     45
```

**high** and **low** range is then taken to determine which columns are selected, and finally sums by index. So my initial code starts by determining difference between columns, query the (`cols`) to be used for the operation

```
def colrange(first, last):
    return (first - last).abs().argsort()[0]

cols = df.columns[:-2]
```

Then I used `iterrows()` to start looking in every row between the range:

```
c = cols.to_series().astype(int)
for idx,row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[idx,'result']= row[cols[ colrange(c,row.low) : colrange(c, row.high) ]].sum()
```

So my `df['result']` should look like:

```
Index     10      20      30     40    50   low    high   result
0         1       20      3      32    9    12     45     1+20+3  = 24
1         10      15      11     11    5    22     41     15+11   = 26
2         20      12      25     9     11   18     33     12      = 12
3         30      18      32     82    11   27     54     32+82     = 114
4         40      32      13     2     2    23     35     32        = 32
5         50      12      4      1     5    15     45     50+12+4   = 66
```

My problem is that this method is too slow, could you advice any other idea how to solve this exercise? I appreciate any thoughts in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is about 5 times faster on your example.
It should also scale pretty good as the DataFrame size increase

```
start = np.abs((c.to_frame().to_numpy().T - df['low'].to_frame().to_numpy())).argsort()[:, 0]
stop = np.abs((c.to_frame().to_numpy().T - df['high'].to_frame().to_numpy())).argsort()[:, 0]
df['result'] = [*map(lambda first, last, row: df.iloc[row, first:last].sum(), start, stop, range(len(df)))]
```

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciated it. I checked it in my dataset and yes! it ran really faster! Now I am figuring out more about the logic used.

Comment: The first two lines are basically a vectorized version of your colrange function. That what makes it faster